# Can someone please tell me how to read the following: /\.(js)$/

Tags: javascript, linux, command-line

I'm trying to understand some webserver code I found online and the part right after the "else if" is the only part I don't understand. (I just started learning this stuff). Thanks

```js
var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    // Managing the root route
    if (path == '/') {
        index = fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html',
            function(error,data) {

                //do stuff...
            });
    // Managing the route for the javascript files
    } else if( /\.(js)$/.test(path) ) {
        index = fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public'+path,
            function(error,data) {

                //do stuff...
            });
```

Comment: It's a regular expression literal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to test against regular expresions.
Heres the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on how it works.

In your example, it's checking if the path ends in .js

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions produce non strict match against the string.
Besides [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) @SpeedOfRound mentioned about it would be useful to play with this [service](https://regex101.com/r/u9cMNm/1/) to get the better understanding on your exact case